# How to select column values which start from specific patterns in Pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame as below. This data for one month period.    I need to select devices who start from ABC.  I need to get my data frame too. ( as my expected output).  How do I do it?

```
Time Stamp              Id  Latitude    Longitude  Device
01/10/2016 15:22:51:700 1      23        50        ABC (aaa)
01/10/2016 16:28:08:026 1      23        50        ABC (aaa)
01/10/2016 16:28:09:026 1      12        45        ABC (bae)
02/10/2016 19:00:08:026 2      23        50        TTT (ff)
02/10/2016 20:28:08:026 1      23        50        GGG (lll)
03/10/2016 19:00:08:000 2      23        50        ABC (zzz)
03/10/2016 01:02:33:123 2      23        50        NNN (gg)
03/10/2016 06:15:08:500 1      23        50        KKK (yyy)
03/10/2016 10:01:07:022 3      28        88        ABC (bae)
......
......
31/10/2016 13:09:17:044 1      33        80        ABC (bae)
```

My expected output is:

```
 Time Stamp             Id  Latitude    Longitude  Device
01/10/2016 15:22:51:700 1      23        50        ABC (aaa)
01/10/2016 16:28:08:026 1      23        50        ABC (aaa)
01/10/2016 16:28:09:026 1      12        45        ABC (bae)
03/10/2016 19:00:08:000 2      23        50        ABC (zzz)
03/10/2016 10:01:07:022 3      28        88        ABC (bae)
......
......
31/10/2016 13:09:17:044 1      33        80        ABC (bae)
```

Comment: The other answers related to this question are not what I want. Those answers weren't help for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `df[df.Device.str.startswith('ABC')]`

With `pandas`, you can use [`series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html) to utilize several useful functions for string manipulation.

[Series.str.startswith](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html), the one I showed above, is to select (return bool values) indices that starts with a specific pattern.

BTW, the answer using `contains` with `^` is basically the same thing but, instead of using a function provided by `pandas`, it uses regex to define the pattern on what should be the first character of your input string.

Comment: @Melchia What?? This is not an answer? You cannot be serious.

Comment: You should explain explain your answer. Once you've done that I'll remove my comment & up-vote.

Comment: @Melchia. Okay, sounds fair. I expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe is called "df", how about using the regexp matching facilities in pandas.Series.str:

```
df[df['Device'].str.contains('^ABC.*')]
```

Comment: Hi, when I do the selection for devices '^Apple iPhone 6 (A1586)', as a result I got empty data frame. I did exact your code. Why I'm getting empty df? ( I need exactly this device only)